# Creating a modular component library package for NPM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm currently creating an npm package that will consist of a series of React components that are common to some applications I am maintaining.

My intention is to be able to import this components individually as needed, not all at once. So for instance if I have the components Accordion, DropDown and Widget, but I'm only using one of them, I'd like for only its code to be required.

My understanding is that I would need to be able to do something like

```
import Widget from 'components/Widget';
```

Instead of

```
import {Widget} from 'components';
```

But I can't get the first version to work. I have not published this package, so I'm using *npm link* to test it on another application. I'm not even sure what to Google to solve the problem myself, so I'd also appreciate links to relevant documentation on this matter.

Thanks.

Comment: The first notation imports the default export from the module components/Widget. The second notation imports a named export by the name of Widget form the components module. If you don't have a Widget.js under the 'components' folder, then the first notation won't work: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Comment: Thanks. I already had those, but I was falsely assuming that setting my entry point to a sub-directory would make it my package's root. Finally figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

So, of course a few minutes after asking my question I resolved the issue:

First, as Yacine Filali commented on my question above, I need to have individual files in order for this to work (this part I had already figured out).

However, I was incorrectly assuming that the root of my package was going to be set to whichever directory my entry file was in. So in package.json I had set

```
"main": "./lib/index.js"
```

Incorrectly assuming that the folder structure would be read from there. After altering my configuration to build everything into the root directory it worked perfectly.

(Of course, I'm now working on a better alternative, like generating a package.json for the lib folder)

Answer (score 0):

In your component:

`export default Widget`

In your index:

`export { default as Component } from './Component'`